# Document, HTMLDocument, Document, Element, Node, etc. What is their relationship?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, bower

I want to know the relationship between `document`, `HTMLDocument`, `Document`, `Element` and `Node` to implement the `getElementsByClassName` method for IE8.. but whenever I try these methods, it's not working : 
`document.getElementsByClassName = function(){}`, `HTMLDocument.getElementsByClassName=function(){}` or 
`Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName=function(){}`.

```js
        if(!Element.getElementsByClassName) {
            Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName = function(arg){
                var cssSelector;
                var parentElement = this.document||this.documentElement.document||document;
                var queryElements = null;

                if(arg){
                    if(arg.indexOf(' ')>0){
                        cssSelector = '[class~="'+arg+'"]';
                    }else{
                        cssSelector = "."+arg;
                    }
                    queryElements = parentElement.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
                }
                return queryElements;
            }
        }
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('limit').item(0);
        var triangles = elems.getElementsByClassName('triangle');
        debugger;
```

Comment: Please define "not working". Console errors ?

Comment: I fear knowing "how it should be" is not really what you need... Been a long time since I worked with IE8, but some older browsers where actually not using the prototype chaining like we are used to now, so changing the prototype of the constructor after the instance had been created was not modifying the instances themselves. But why are you doing it yourself? There are many such polyfills heavily tested available online (btw looking at [one of these](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/HEAD/dom.js), they do modify the instance, not the proto)

Answer (score 0):

You could find the description of `Document`, `Node` and `Element` in [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction#Important_Data_Types) and the description of `HTMLDocument` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument).

- The `Document` interface represents any web page loaded in the browser and serves as an entry point into the web page's content, which is the DOM tree.
- `Node` is an interface from which various types of DOM API objects inherit.
- `Element` is one kind of `Node`. It only has methods and properties common to all kinds of elements.
- The `HTMLDocument` interface, extends the `Window.HTMLDocument` property to include methods and properties that are specific to HTML documents.

Besides, if you just want to use something like `getElementsByClassName` in IE 8, I think the simplest way is to use `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` as a replacement. For more information about this method, you could refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: "Element is the most general base..." hum nope. You were thinking of Node maybe?

Comment: I got the explanation from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Comment: Well that's just wrong. All objects in a Document do inherit from Node, not from Element. Take for instance in any valid HTML5 document, `document.firstChild` will be the `<!DOCTYPE html>` node, which **is not an Element**. (`document.firstChild instanceof Element` ==> `false`, `document.firstChild instanceof DocumentType` ==> `true`, `document.firstChild instanceof Node` ==> `true`).  Same goes for all #text nodes, all attributes nodes etc. Beware MDN is written and maintained by volunteers and is not official (even if of general good quality).

Comment: I see, element inherits from node and is based on node. Element is element node. I've tested with your code. Totally right. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.